# last appended option in select tag always becomes the value of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an select element in js with the help of jquery. I first build the select tag and then append the options tag to it. While doing so I set the selected attribute to one of the options tag while building it. Even then irrespective of which option tag has the selected attribute the last appended option seems to taken as the value for the select field. This is the case only in Firefox , chrome and IE works fine.
Is it something I am missing to understand or a known problem?

Html

```
<select id="test">
</select>
```

JS

```
var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
$("#test").append("<option value='one' selected='selected'>one</option>");
$("#test").append("<option value='two' >two</option>");
$("#test").prepend("<option value='zero' >zero</option>");
var a = $("#test").children().get();
$("#test").children().remove();
$("#test").append(a);
```

fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/AfT3Z/

Comment: Yup, I can reproduce in Firefox. Maybe you could take this into account and dynamically decide what's the last option given the `selected` attribute.

Comment: it looks more crazy if you look at the `option:selected` filter after the elements are removed from dom http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XSfK2/1/ if the `remove` part is commented then `option:selected` will give 1 result else 3 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XSfK2/2/ ... what is that?

Comment: @ArunPJohny this doesn't work on FF

Comment: @Jonathan I know that.... it was just a demo... the problem is not that the last appended item is selected... it is that all the options after the one that is marked as selected it marked as selected once those are removed from the dom

Comment: @ArunPJohny that is why he should use clone. See my answer edits.

Comment: @Jonathan I think the question is why is this behavior?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e5ZPh/ - All following options after the first `selected` also give true for `.selected` and after appending them back to the DOM only the last one is `true` despite the `selected` attribute is still correctly set... Strange behaviour... (FF24, IE8 (at work...))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this code supposed to do?

```
var a = $("#test").children().get();
$("#test").children().remove();
$("#test").append(a);
```

Removing it it works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/AfT3Z/1/

**EDIT:**

If you need the code I removed you can modify it this way:

```
var a = $("#test").html();
$("#test").children().remove();
$("#test").html(a);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AfT3Z/2/

This way you don't loose on the way the `selected` attribute.

**EDIT #2:**

You can even clone the children to obtain an exact copy of them:

```
var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
$("#test").append("<option value='one' selected='selected'>one</option>");
$("#test").append("<option value='two' >two</option>");
$("#test").prepend("<option value='zero' >zero</option>");

var a = $("#test").children().clone();
$("#test").children().remove();
$("#test").append(a);
```

Comment: Hi, I understand it does not make sense to remove child and add it again . It was done basically to maintain some order in the options I believe I just simulated it in a simple way to describe my problem. In actual code we dynamically add options based on many check even then I my wonder is why it has to behave in such a manner

Comment: Instead of children().get() on the select , .html() on the select maintains the attributes and is working fine.